# favicon not showing in the address bar

Tags: favicon

I am using Dreamweaver and I tried to create a favicon to show logo on the address bar and i put this tag in the head tag of html page

```
 <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

also I tried the ".ico" extension but still nothing is shown on the address bar browsers (chrome - firecox and internet explorer) 
so any suggestion as I followed the steps as this link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: Can you clear cache and try? And share your browser versions as well.

Comment: i am using chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)
also i have cleared the cache history cookies of the browser and still not showing

Comment: am using same chrome version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit) and its working fine. Check whether href path is correct or not and image is available or not.

Comment: its solved i cleared the cache as u told me and then i closed everything and started it again and its working now thanks alot